# Intersystems Cache - How to Enable/Configure Security Services

Tags: intersystems-cache

Looking to create a script that will enable/configure snmp and related settings.

Through the web portal it would be placed in: 
[Home] > [Security Management] > [Services] > Service_Monitor

Would like to be able to enable, add allowed IP Addresses, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Security.Services class in %SYS namespace. You may use Export/Import methods to store settings in a file or Get/Set methods to modify service properties directly.